# How do I find out what's getting passed to this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, jsp

I have the following JavaScript function inside a JSP page (data replaced with metasyntactic variables):

```
$.post("foo",
    {
         bar : StrBar,
         baz : StrBaz

    },
    function(data, status) {



         if (data) {
              // Inner code left out for brevity

         }
         else{
             // Inner code left out for brevity

         }
    }
);
```

The problem I'm having is that the wrong branch of the code is executing, and I don't know how to find out what data are being passed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hit F12 and use the browser's debugging tool. You should see the network transaction, the request and response headers, content, etc.

Comment: [how to use the console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/)

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  However, the function is, unfortunately, an argument in a `$.post` statement.  Thus, I can't directly look at it through the console.

Comment: again, hit F12 and look into `Sources` tab, find this JS and see

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` may give you a hint at the contents.

Comment: Yes it's inside `$.post` but you should still be able to set a breakpoint on, e.g. the `if(data){}` line

Comment: @Rhumborl That seems to have worked.  If your comment were an answer I would have accepted it.

Comment: Actually @Rhumborl could you please convert your comment into an answer?  It just doesn't feel right to me to deny you the rep you deserve for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rhumborl said in his comment:

> Yes it's inside `$.post` but you should still be able to set a breakpoint on, e.g. the `if(data){}` line

I did not know when I posted the question that I could set a breakpoint in the middle of the `$.post`, and setting such a breakpoint solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `console.log` function.

You can put this in your functions and it will silently output the information without interrupting the UI (like alert would do).  This means that you can leave them in without worrying about accidentally leaving them in and causing problems when you deploy it to production.

```
var x = {value:"F"}

console.log(x);



function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);

     if (data) {
          // Inner code left out for brevity

     }
     else{
         // Inner code left out for brevity

     }
```

Chrome's Developer Tools will show the object properties and their values.